# Debugging Server connection interrupted messages

Tags: time-capsule

I'm suffering at irregular intervals on my network with:

[image: Time capsule series 1]

Does anyone have some practical advice how to limit this? I don't understand what the problem is. The new Macbook Air with Mountain Lion has no problem pinging 192.168.1.2 (the Time Capsule) on my [home network](http://prazefarm.co.uk/network/network-config.txt).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and wrote [this post](http://whatsamknows.tumblr.com/post/37368603810/get-rid-of-server-connections-interrupted) with the answer:

The fix is to remove/disable `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/FSDisconnect.loginPlugin`

The following steps should sort you out:

1. Click on the spotlight icon (magnifying glass) in the upper right of your screen
2. Type in ‘terminal’
3. Click the ‘Terminal’ icon (black with white border) under applications
4. Type in the following command (and hit enter):

   `sudo mv /System/Library/LoginPlugins/FSDisconnect.loginPlugin /System/`
5. It will prompt you for your user password. Type it and hit enter again
6. Reboot

This just moves the plugin to `/System` so you can restore it again if needed by replacing step #4 with `sudo mv /System/FSDisconnect.loginPlugin /System/Library/LoginPlugins/`.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.